# Share link with facebook in flex

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I've Shared one link with facebook using my flex 3 application.

my code is:

```
<mx:Button id="btnFb" click="fbShare(event)" />

  protected function fbShare(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
     openPage('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+getPublicationUrl(),"_popup");
  }

  private function getPublicationUrl():String
  {
      return "http://domain.com/index.html?userid=3&pubid=10";
  }
```

Now When i share this(above) link with facebook then it will share only "http://domain.com/index.html?userid=3" this link. it will skip **&pubid=10**.

Thanks,

Comment: probably have to escape &

Comment: Yes, But i like to pass &pubid=10 with url then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the encodeURIComponent function on the return data of the getPublicationURL function:

```
private function getPublicationUrl():String
{
    return encodeURIComponent("http://domain.com/index.html?userid=3&pubid=10");
}
```

The core issue was that the original URL was taking on the &pubid parameter because it was not encoded.  More info about escape, encodeURI and encodeURIComponent is available here:

[When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)